# Adding a Directory to a Path in .profile

Tags: home-directory, paths, user-profile

I am new to Ubuntu (coming from Windows 7) and I am trying to add a directory to my system path and for some reason I can't get it to work. I am using Ubuntu version 12.04 LTS

I tried following this article without success [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Here are my steps:

1. In my home directory I am editing the .profile file.
2. Under the “# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists” section I added    the following:

   ```
   if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then 
      PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH:home/vincent/google_appengine"  
   fi
   ```
3. I logout and log back in.
4. open the terminal window and type in:

   ```
   vincent@ubuntu:~$ dev_appserver.py 
   dev_appserver.py: command not found
   ```

The directory and files are in the location.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The code in the `if` statement is only used if there's a directory `$HOME/bin` is a directory
- I needs to be `/home/vincent/google_appengine` instead of `home/vincent/google_appengine` or (even better) `$HOME/google_appengine` because `home` is relative and `/home` is absolute.

Use

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/google_appengine"
```

Remember anything in the `$PATH` before `google_appengine` will override it.

Answer (score 4):

Add this line at the end of .profile(or not inside an if statement):

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/vincent/google_appengine
```

Example .profile :

```
.

.

export LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"

export PATH=$PATH:/home/vincent/google_appengine
```

Comment: +1 Thanks pl1nk! I tried the accepted answer the first time and it worked.

Comment: @Zaffiro - You are welcome, you were both posting at the same time :)