# Can I log in without loading my .profile?

Tags: 14.04, recovery-mode, .profile

I recently inserted an error into my `.profile` file and now logging in just presents me back to the log in page, much like in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148571/ubuntu-stuck-in-a-login-loop-after-editing-profile-file#_=_). I've booted into recovery mode and recovered my encrypted `/home/` partition, but I can't edit `.profile` from there. I know how to fix the file, just not how to get to do so. What are my options?

Comment: An error in my `.profile` does not prevent me from logging in to the TTY (Ctrl-Alt-F1 to F6). Did you try the TTY?

Comment: I can log in that way but bash commands don't work due to the `.profile` error.

Comment: No commands at all? Even with full paths (`/usr/bin/nano` instead of `nano`, etc.)?

Comment: Full paths of course! Sorted now, thanks for the help. Can you post this as an answer and I'll accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While an error in `.profile` does cause the GUI to loop back to the login screen, you can log in to the TTYs (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd> (or <kbd>F2</kbd> through <kbd>F6</kbd>)). Depending on your specific problem, your `PATH` may or may not be affected. If you find you cannot run commands, try with full paths (`/usr/bin/nano` vs just `nano`).